# How to unit test UIView's frame after applying CGAffineTransform(translationX)

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I want to test the following method using `Quick`:

```
func initial(states: UIView...) {
    for view in states {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 20)
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using for testing (simplified version):

```
class ProtocolsSpec: QuickSpec {    
    override func spec() {
        var view1: UIView!
        var view2: UIView!

        describe("Animator") {
            beforeEach {
                view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50))
                view2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 50, height: 50))
            }

            it("views origin should be (0, 20) at startup") {
                initial(states: view1, view2)

                expect(view1.frame.origin.x) == 0
                expect(view1.frame.origin.y) == 20
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The tests doesn't work, the x and y are not changed.
My question is how to get the correct (x,y) coordinates after applying the transformation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `frame`, `center`, and `bounds` properties will not change after applying transformations. The documentation of `frame` even states that:

> If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.
>
> [API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622621-frame)

In order to get the effective frame I'd suggest applying the views transform onto the views frame (using the `applying(_:)` method on `CGRect`. In your case that would look like:

```
let resultingFrame = view1.frame.applying(view1.transform)
expect(resultingFrame.origin.x) == 0
expect(resultingFrame.origin.y) == 20
```